# Optimizing delete operation of 50 millions of records from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to delete approximately 50 million of records (and not whole table)
I searched and found some ways to do it

This query does what i want, i can optimize it a little bit by storing results of sub queries in a  `#TempTable`

What else can i do?

The fastest query so far :

```
CREATE TABLE #UserIDs ( UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  NOT NULL  );
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX myIndex ON #UserIDs (UserId)

INSERT INTO #UserIDs 
SELECT UserId FROM TableX WHERE UserID IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO #UserIDs 
SELECT UserID FROM TableY WHERE CreatorID IS NOT NULL;

    DELETE TOP (10000)
    FROM Users
    WHERE 
        Email IS NULL
        AND
        (
            (NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM #UserIDs WHERE #UserIDs.UserId = Users.UserId ) )
        )

DROP TABLE #UserIDs
```

[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: AND UserId NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM TableX UNION SELECT UserId FROM TableY)

Comment: Actually the index on SomeCondition doesn't help in this case. But do you have an index on UserId? Can we see an execution plan?

Comment: No there are records that should not be deleted and @Dd2 yes UserId column also indexed.

Comment: Depending on the sizes and indexes on tablex and tabley using not exists may be faster

Comment: How fragmented are your indexes?

Comment: Verify that all foreign keys targeting `Users` are indexed. Sql Server will check if it is allowed to delete a record by checking foreign keys; if they are not indexed Sql Server will have to perform table scan instead of index lookup.

Comment: UserID is `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`

Comment: SQL Server shows Fragmention percent of UserID like 99.1659096807682

Comment: if fragmentation if more than 30% => you have to rebuild your index...

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a solution to temporary set recovery model to SIMPLE?

Comment: Please show the query plan of the delete as it stands. It will tell us about the table structure.

Comment: How many records are in the table?

Comment: ~58 millions of record

Comment: Execution plan added to the question

Comment: Given that you're deleting 86% of the data, selecting what you want to keep and switching out tables makes much more sense, I vote for copying the records to keep, rebuild indexes on it, then drop existing and rename new table.

Comment: How about DISABLE all constraints of the table TEMPORARILY then process DELETE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the number of records you want to preserve is small comparing to number of records you need to delete, I would copy them to temporary table, then TRUNCATE the original table and insert preserved records back from temporary table. Table truncation works very fast, so you may save much time. However TRUNCATE TABLE not always work, but it can be a solution for you.

Comment: I love it, unless there might be users accessing the table.

Comment: You can do it in transaction and use TABLOCKX to protect the table (shouldn't block for more than a few seconds, but test it first on another instance). The trouble with TRUNCATE is that there can't be any FOREIGN KEY on the table, so you may want to drop and recreate them too. May seem little troublesome, but can potentially save several hours.

Comment: This gets my vote given 58 million rows in the table.  I would suggest copy out, build indexes on new, dropping old and renaming new would be faster than truncating/inserting, but that's minor.

Comment: If you want to minimize impact... you can create the new table as tmpUsers, fill it with data you want to keep, drop the old table, then rename tmpUser to Users.

Comment: @samyi this way you lose permissions, triggers, indexes and other object created on the original table.

Comment: @Endrju, agreed. Those should be scripted.

Answer (score 2):

Run part 1 first:

```
SELECT u.UserId
INTO #DeleteThis
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN tableX x
    ON u.UserId = x.UserId
LEFT JOIN tableY y
    ON u.UserId = y.UserId
WHERE SomeCondition IS NULL --SomeCondition is indexed
    AND x.UserId IS NULL
    AND y.UserId IS NULL
```

Then run part 2:

```
DELETE TOP (1000)
FROM Users u
JOIN #DeleteThis d    
    ON u.UserId = d.UserId

GO 50000
```

Answer (score 2):

Without being able to see the execution plane, it's hard to say, but ...

I'd be inclined to create a work table containing the list of "keepers": anybody not in that list gets deleted: a one-time, up-front cost to compile that list.

Assuming `userId` is the primary key of the user table and is indexed, the work table contains only `userId`, which is defined as `primary key clustered`. This means the delete statement just needs to probe the work table to determine what rows need to deleted from the user table. Then it's a simple matter of something like this:

```
--
-- create/populate our work table containing the list of keepers
-- anybody not in this list gets deleted
--
create table #keepers
(
  userId int not null primary key clustered ,
)

insert #keepers (userId)
select t.userId
from dbo.Users t
join dbo.TableX x on x.userId = t.userId
join dbo.TableY y on y.userId = t.userID
where t.someCondition is not null

--
-- iterate, deleting a batch at a time until nothing has been deleted
--
declare @batch_size int     = 10000 -- or whatever you decide is good
declare @finished   char(1) = 'N'
while ( @finished = 'N' )
begin

  delete top @batch_size dbo.Users
  from dbo.Users t
  where not exists ( select *
                     from #keepers k
                     where k.userID = t.userId
                   )

  set @finished = case @@rowcount when 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end
end
```

If the nature of your application is such that users may transition from the keeper list to the loser list while this process is going on, you might want to try something like the following. Correlated subqueries with `exists` are usually a better idea (assuming some rational indexing scheme) than is the uncorrellated `not in`. So, something like this might perform better:

```
declare @batch_size int     = 10000 -- or whatever you decide is good
declare @finished   char(1) = 'N'
while ( @finished = 'N' )
begin

  delete top @batch_size dbo.Users
  from dbo.Users t
  where u.someCondition is null
    and (    not exists ( select * from dbo.tableX x on x.userID = u.userId )
          OR not exists ( select * from dbo.tableY y on y.userID = u.userId )
        )

  set @finished = case @@rowcount when 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end
end
```

Comment: I also provided an answer with the "keeper" concept but i wonder if that's a feasible solution. What if a particular userid gets added to TableX during the deletion process? Should you create FK before beginning delete?

Comment: I think i will merge solutions that you and @samyi provided and go for it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
DELETE FROM Users
WHERE 
SomeCondition IS NULL --SomeCondition is indexed
AND
(
    (NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM TableX WHERE TableX.UserId = Users.UserId ) )
    OR
    (NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM TableY WHERE TableY.UserId = Users.UserId ) )
)
```

Run it and let me know your result.

Comment: I deleted 1000 records and it took 4 seconds, but when i try to increase record number to 10000 it took 3 minute and i canceled it out.

Comment: Endrju answer will be the fastest.

Comment: Surprised to hear your result. I thought it is faster than your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking to the following scenario:

1/ Create a new table called "UsersClone", as a copy of "Users" table

2/ Delete the records in clone peacefully

3/ Add in clone newly added users (if any)

4/ Rename "Users" as "UsersToDelete" (see sp_rename)

5/ Rename the clone as "Users"

6/ Drop table "UsersToDelete"

What do you think about?

Comment: It looks like i will do it if i couldn't find a better way.

Comment: Copying of 50 mln rows will be time consuming and will require a lot of transaction log space if table is not very narrow.

Comment: @Endrju: Time is not important as long users can log in. In this scenario counts better performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of rows you want to keep is small I suggest you go with the copy-to-new-table approach. If the number is high, the downtime will be too long and you can't do it.

You've got a problem at the moment because every execution of the delete script is going to take longer than the previous one. Bigger and bigger parts of the table must be scanned to find rows to delete.

Honestly, your table should be a clustered index on the ID column. But given that it is not, I recommend that you materialize all user-ids to delete into a temp table. Put a clustered index on that temp table's UserID column. All of this is online.

Next, you delete from the heap in batches like this:

```
DELETE TOP (1000) u
FROM Users u
JOIN #userIDs ids on u.ID = ids.UserID --uses indexes on both tables
WHERE ids.UserID > @lastDeletedUserID --start where last batch stopped
ORDER BY ids.UserID --delete in order of the table
```

This will take the same amount of time for each iteration. You just have to keep track of the last ID that was deleted (`@lastDeletedUserID`).

Comment: When the delete's outweigh the keeps so handily, no sense in separating out the records to delete, then deleting.

Comment: @GoatCO of course, just truncate the table or recreate it if you use the insert approach.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the Truncates, have you tried moving the sub-selects out into a separate section? You are querying that set of data over and over again, it might be faster to dump it into a temporary table and use it?

```
Declare @temp Table (ID int)

Insert into @temp
select UserId FROM TableX
union
select UserId FROM TableY;

DoItAgain:
    DELETE TOP (1000)
    FROM Users
    WHERE 
        SomeCondition IS NULL --SomeCondition is indexed
        AND UserID not in (select UserId From @temp)

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
GOTO DoItAgain
```

Comment: In execution plan you can see that i used this method.